# What are the differences of defining configMap in volumes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I'm just curious about what are the differences between these 2 ways of defining `ConfigMap` in `volumes` section?

p.s. `test-config` is including `config.json` file.

`newpod.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: configmappod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: configmapcontainer
    image: blue
    volumeMounts:
      - name: config-vol
        mountPath: "/config/newConfig.json"
        subPath: "config.json"
        readOnly: true
  volumes:
    - name: config-vol
      projected:
        sources:
        - configMap:
            name: test-config
            items:
              - key: config.json
                path: config.json
```

`newpod2.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: configmappod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: configmapcontainer
    image: blue
    volumeMounts:
      - name: config-vol
        mountPath: "/config/newConfig.json"
        subPath: "config.json"
        readOnly: true
  volumes:
    - name: config-vol
      configMap:
        name: test-config
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No different, they yield the same result. By the way, the `readOnly` attribute is redundant, it does not have any effect in both cases.